# opportunity Product not showing up in relationship

Tags: custom-object

I have created a custom object called funding and I am trying to related it you to Opportunity Product object using the data type lookup relationship however when I review the list Opportunity Product is not on the list, why?

Answer (score 1):

Because it's not allowed. Certain child objects, like OpportunityLineItem, OrderLineItem, OpportunityLineItemSchedule, etc, do not support lookup relationships. This is simply a limitation of the platform. I'm not sure where, or if, it's in the documentation, but you'll find that only objects that support tabs can be in lookup relationships. If the object can't have a tab, it can't be the parent in a relationship (note: there may be exceptions to this rule, but I don't recall seeing any).

Comment: I never thought about the tab connection until you pointed it out. Note that, perhaps because of the tab "feature", global search from the UI won't find `OrderItem` records even if the search field is indexed (I didn't try for OLI and QI as our org doesn't use those)

Answer (score 0):

Updating the correct answer to note that lookup relationships using Opportunity Products are possible as of [Spring 21](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_sales_features_core_opportunities_line_item_lookup.htm&type=5&release=230).